# Can you enable chrome / chromium edge extensions on the extension pages?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension, microsoft-edge-chromium

When I'm browsing for extensions on either the Microsoft Extension Store (`microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons`) or the Chrome Web Store (`chrome.google.com/webstore`), I always hate that none of my extensions work on those sites. Is there any way to enable extensions on these? I'd be willing to do anything possible to enable it (registry edits, browser exe changes, etc).

Comment: You'll have to modify the source code of Chromium/Edge or hack/patch the binary.

Comment: Do you know of any way to do that?